# script to enable Instant File Initialization with secedit

Tags: windows, security, powershell

I'd like to be able to turn on IFI http://bit.ly/1dK32Dc on a new or existing Windows Server box with SQL Server, via T-SQL or Powershell. Don't want to go through the "Local Security > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Perform volume maintenance tasks > Add user" route - need to deploy new machines through a script, no manual interaction. Assume the SQL Server service account doesn't change.

For new installs, when I choose the account, I'm able to run the below Powershell script and it solves the problem:

```
$sqlaccount = "domain\account"
# https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490997.aspx
secedit /export /cfg C:\secexport.txt /areas USER_RIGHTS
$line = Get-Content C:\secexport.txt | Select-String 'SeManageVolumePrivilege'
(Get-Content C:\secexport.txt).Replace($line,"$line,$sqlaccount") | Out-File C:\secimport.txt
secedit /configure /db secedit.sdb /cfg C:\secimport.txt /overwrite /areas USER_RIGHTS
```

However, for existing SQL installs, can't figure a way to query the configured SQL Server service account - and feed it to this script. Looking for a solution with WS 2012 R2 in mind, but something that would also work on WS 2003 R2 would be best (supports up to Powershell 2 if I'm not mistaken ?).

Comment: You want to get the account that is running the SQL service, correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter with SQL, the following command dose not add any users to Perform volume maintenance task, is this limited to specific version of windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Get-WmiObject win32_service | where { $_.displayname -eq "SQL Server"} ).startname`

Replace the name with the displayname of your SQL server service

Comment: Great, it works in WS 2012R2 ! Just to add something that might be of help: Get-WmiObject win32_service | Format-Table Name, DisplayName, State, StartMode, StartName and to find out the service if you use instances Get-WmiObject win32_service | where { $_.DisplayName -like "*SQL*"} | Format-Table Name, DisplayName, State, StartMode, StartName

Answer (score 1):

Works fine, but in windows server 2016 it hangs on secedit configure. To avoid this, just add:

**Write-Host "y" |** secedit /configure /db secedit.sdb /cfg C:\secimport.txt /overwrite /areas USER_RIGHTS

Comment: I would prefer to user secedit .... /quiet